# What is affected in the Page/Control life cycle when an asp.net control has no ID

Tags: asp.net, controls

If in the markup you declare a control like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtSomeInput">Some Input:</asp:Label>
<asp:Textbox id="txtSomeInput" runat="server" />
```

Does leaving out the ID from the label control change anything in regards to Viewstate or the Page/Control life cycle? Does it just get some generated ID? Obviously it cannot be referenced in the code-behind at design time (well at least not by the programmer)...Just curious as to if this has any side effects (or tangible benefits)?

Further, I would presume if this control cannot be referenced at design time it can't really be changed in a way that would add any information to viewstate...yet the runat tag allows the AssociatedControlID to be decided (master page crap ids for example) thus not having to have a html label with a <%# %> to write the clientId??

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference from a functionality perspective. Elements which require an ID to function properly will auto-generate one. It does make referencing the control by name in the code-behind difficult, but still possible, it just requires manually finding it and wiring it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I was only really interested in removing the ID from controls that don't need an referencing...where a control needs referencing, that's what an ID is for...

Answer (score 0):

Some side-effects are if you're using some tools that run script client-side.  For example, a button without an ID cannot properly trigger an update panel operation correctly (in most cases) because when the javascript is created rendering what clicks should be captured/re-routed as partial postbacks...the lack of an ID leaves it out of the list  *(Think, what javascript could you manually run to attach the handler without it?)*.

The button just needs the right click handler, the ID doesn't matter for what it triggers server-side...but this leaves client-script needing more a lot of times.

As a side note: If you haven't looked at .Net 4, I suggest you take a look, [the situation has vastly improved with ClientIDs](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx).

Comment: Good points, I've been waiting for .Net 4 for ages...when they announced some of the benefits last year it really will give WebForms some extra credibility